# Weight for an extrinsic that schedule another call in the future?

Tags: benchmarking, weight, pallet-scheduler

I have an extrinsic for a poll that will end in the future. I used scheduller pallet to make the end of the poll execute. The end of the poll is then made by a root call.

Should I add the weight of both extrinsics, create and enactment, to the creation of the call so to charge the user?

Is this correct?

Comment: Where do you want to add the weight? The scheduler pallet does not charge any user for the weight, since its used by governance. I dont quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I have two extrinsics. Create and enactment. Create adds enactment to the agenda. I was wondering If I should add the weight of both, creation and enactment to creation. So when a user creates a poll it would pay for both.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: `create` creates a poll that will end at block X, presenting a poll whether or not to enact a call. `Enactment` will execute the call included in the poll (if it is accepted) at block X.

Weight for a call needs to be included when the call is actually executed. As for a scheduled call this is done at [`on_initialize`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/7cbe0c76ef8fd2aabf9f07de0156941ce3ed44b0/substrate/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L320-L324).

Like Oliver said, the caller of a scheduled call doesn't have to pay in advance for the execution. However the weight **is** measured when the call is executed (otherwise this opens up possible attacks).